# Cypress dependency module Stub not working and throwing error while running

Tags: node.js, cypress, stub

I've a below JS File

**foo.js**

```
const crudService=require(./pg-db-pool)

    function allrecords () {
      return 3
    }
```

I've the below cypress test file. I'm planning to mock the crudService.listAllRecords and return a constant value.

**testfile.spec.js(original)**

```
const foo = require('./foo')
   describe('Testing', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        cy.stub(foo, 'allrecords').returns(10)
      })
      it('crud test - list', async () => {
        const list = foo.allrecords()
        expect(list).to.equal('10')
      })
    })
```

While executing the test run, it's throwing below error because it was not stubbing correctly.

```
    Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:
    
      cypress/integration/api/routes/utils/foo.js
    
    The error was:
    
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/pg/lib/native/client.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-native' in './node_modules/pg/lib/native'
resolve 'pg-native' in './node_modules/pg/lib/native'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: ./node_modules/pg/package.json (relative path: ./lib/native)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths:
```

If I comment the first line of foo.js like below, it works fine.

**fool.js(modified)**

```
//const crudService=require(./pg-db-pool)

    function allrecords () {
      return 3
    }
```

Please help me to stub for the scenario mentioned in original foo.js